# Underscore JS Sortby multi dimensional

Tags: underscore.js

Can anyone help with sorting a multi dimensional list using underscore

e.g

```
    [
  {
    "pageid": "129",
    "PageTitle": "cp2 pg1",
    "Index": [
      {
        "title": "Index-1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "pageid": "130",
    "PageTitle": "cp2 pg1",
    "Index": [
      {
        "title": "Index-3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "pageid": "170",
    "PageTitle": "cp2 pg1",
    "Index": [
      {
        "title": "Index-2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and I want to order them by the index title so I get index 1, 2 and then 3.

Here is my attempt so far:

```
var prevpage_nav_obj = _.sortBy(prevpage_nav_obj, function (item) {
                item.Index.title
            });
```

Comment: What if one page has multiple titles?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `Index` property is an array, not directly a string, so your indexed value should look like `item.Index[0].title` or an adequate value taken from your array
2. you forgot to return the indexed value

which leads to

```
_.sortBy(prevpage_nav_obj, function (item) {
    return item.Index[0].title;
});
```

and a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/Mn6J5/1/